# pyqtgraph scatterplotitem setbrush

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I am trying to pass list argument through setBrush.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
mw.resize(800,800)
view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()  
mw.setCentralWidget(view)
mw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ScatterPlot')
w1 = view.addPlot()
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [10,8,6,4,2,20,18,16,14,12]
s1 = pg.ScatterPlotItem(x,y,size=10, pen=pg.mkPen(None), brush=pg.mkBrush(255, 255, 255, 120))
s1.setBrush(['r']*10, mask=None)
w1.addItem(s1)
mw.show()
```

When I run this code, I am getting error as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>
> File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ScatterPlotItem.py",
>   line 467, in setBrush
>       self.updateSpots(dataSet)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ScatterPlotItem.py",
>   line 553, in updateSpots
>       self.fragmentAtlas.getAtlas() # generate atlas so source widths are available.
>
> File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ScatterPlotItem.py",
>   line 193, in getAtlas
>       self.buildAtlas()
>
> File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ScatterPlotItem.py",
>   line 143, in buildAtlas
>       img = renderSymbol(key[0], key[1], sourceRect.pen, sourceRect.brush)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ScatterPlotItem.py",
>   line 74, in renderSymbol
>       drawSymbol(p, symbol, size, pen, brush)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\ScatterPlotItem.py",
>   line 49, in drawSymbol
>       painter.setBrush(brush) TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:   QPainter.setBrush(QBrush): argument 1 has
>   unexpected type 'str'   QPainter.setBrush(Qt.BrushStyle): argument 1
>   has unexpected type 'str'

How can I pass list though setBrush? I have to assign different color to different points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `s.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush({your parameters}))`
by example:

- QtGui.QBrush()
- QtGui.QBrush(Qt.BrushStyle bs)
- QtGui.QBrush(QColor color, Qt.BrushStyle style = Qt.SolidPattern)
- QtGui.QBrush(Qt.GlobalColor color, Qt.BrushStyle style = Qt.SolidPattern)
- QtGui.QBrush(QColor color, QPixmap pixmap)
- QtGui.QBrush(Qt.GlobalColor color, QPixmap pixmap)
- QtGui.QBrush(QPixmap pixmap)
- QtGui.QBrush(QImage image)
- QtGui.QBrush(QGradient gradient)
- QtGui.QBrush(QBrush brush)
- QtGui.QBrush(QVariant variant)

In your Code:

```
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
mw.resize(800, 800)
view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
mw.setCentralWidget(view)
mw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ScatterPlot')
w1 = view.addPlot()
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12]

# Create seed for the random
time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
QtCore.qsrand(time.msec())

for i in range(len(x)):
    s = pg.ScatterPlotItem([x[i]], [y[i]], size=10, pen=pg.mkPen(None))  # brush=pg.mkBrush(255, 255, 255, 120))
    s.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.qrand() % 256, QtCore.qrand() % 256, QtCore.qrand() % 256)))
    w1.addItem(s)
mw.show()
sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to set the red color for the first 5 points (x: 1-5) and blue for another 5 points (x: 6-10)

```
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
mw.resize(800, 800)
view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
mw.setCentralWidget(view)
mw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ScatterPlot')
w1 = view.addPlot()
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12]

color = QtGui.QColor("#0000FF")
s = pg.ScatterPlotItem(x[:5], y[:5], size=10, pen=pg.mkPen(None), brush='r')
w1.addItem(s)
s = pg.ScatterPlotItem(x[5:], y[5:], size=10, pen=pg.mkPen(None), brush='b')
w1.addItem(s)
mw.show()
sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much :) Can I setbrush color red for first 5 points (x : 1-5) and blue for another 5 points (x: 6-10)?

Comment: @eyllanesc Could you please help me out, i need time stamps in x-axis. my x values are x = ['0:09:43', '0:09:44', '0:09:45', '0:09:46', '0:09:47', '0:09:48', '0:09:49', '0:09:50', '0:09:51', '0:09:52', '0:09:53', '0:09:54', '0:09:55', '0:09:56', '0:09:57']

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the color of your dots, you can pass a list to the `symbolBrush` keyword. Your code then becomes:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import time
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
mw.resize(800,800)
view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
mw.setCentralWidget(view)
mw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ScatterPlot')
w1 = view.addPlot()
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [10,8,6,4,2,20,18,16,14,12]

brush_list = [pg.mkColor(c) for c in "rgbcmykwrg"]

p1 = w1.plot()
s1 = p1.setData(x=x, y=y, size=10, pen=pg.mkPen(None), brush='g', symbol='o', symbolBrush=brush_list, symbolPen='r')
mw.show()
sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
```

I needed to do `p1 = w1.plot()` to make it work, but I'm not fluent enough in all the pyqtgraph objects to tell you what that does.

I had to convert the color string (or tuple or whatever) into a `pg.mkColor()` object for it to work (although the docs say it isn't needed)

Note that the `brush` keyword fills the graph until a certain value you specify (e.g. the x-axis), which is useful for lines, but doesn't show anything for points, as you can see in the image.

The `symbolPen` keyword can be used for the line color of your points.

[image]